# Servlet can't read XMLHttpRequest parameter

Tags: javascript, java, servlets, xmlhttprequest

I am creating a HTTP POST request from JavaScript like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="num" type="text" />
    <input type="button" id="btn" value="submit" onclick="func()"/>
    <script>
    function func() {
        var num = document.getElementById("num").value;
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open("POST", "/Servlet/MyServlet", true);
        request.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
                 ...        }
        };
        request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/www-x-form-urlencoded");
        request.send("num=" + num);
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is my servlet:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
              ...
            int num = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("num"));            
    }
```

The servlet is called, but the parameter is `null`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the issue: It is the `setRequestHeader` line. Yours is `application/www-x-form-urlencoded` which should be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Try replacing the below line into your code. Otherwise your code works like charm (I have tried it).

```
 request.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems OK, try printing out all the parameters you get with `request.getParameterMap();`
What are you passing as a parameter in num variable? I am assuming it's a number but if it's a string you need to make sure it's URL encoded as well